# How to get top, bottom and middle data from a file

Tags: python, sorting

I have a datafile.txt with 2 columns. I am currently sorting using excel and I want to try using python to implementing sorting the contents. I am searching for possible ideas and your ideas and help will a lot.

datafile.txt #- 25 lines of data

```
    UQ8SAI       12.539
    V2LCFW      -11.487
    KCP5LY       10.31
    I2GYD5        7.321
    BOONZZ       -5.652
    BL19JU        0.669
    0E10MH       -8.472
    SRS7A0       -0.5
    0IS2PR       -0.686
    PL7BMP        0.561
    D4SBIM      -14.535
    NTT0RP        3.339
    7U2SWD       -7.216
    2B2L1X       20.31
    OEMHED       -0.561
    6F6SR8        5.652
    1GPMVW       -0.3401
    3GYYED        0.821
    21N6JN       -5.292
    DBSUQ1       -6.3403
    FXE8UH        3.1012
    LFB00W       -4.9191
    COSZVU        0.0132
    DBSUQ3        6.923
    QQTW8M        7.2584
```

#- code currently working on from @Tim Roberts

```
import pandas as pd
data = {}
for row in open('x.csv'):
    cols = row.rstrip().split()
    if cols[2] not in data:
        data[cols[2]] = {}
    data[cols[2]][cols[0]] = cols[1]
print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output Needed:

```
#- Upper 5 (positive highest to lowest)
2B2L1X      20.31
UQ8SAI      12.539
KCP5LY      10.31
I2GYD5       7.321
QQTW8M       7.2584

#- Middle 1 (Top 4 starting from -0 to -2 or more)
0IS2PR      -0.686
OEMHED      -0.561
SRS7A0      -0.5
1GPMVW      -0.3401

#- Middle 2 (Top 4 stating from +0 to +2 or more)
3GYYED       0.821
BL19JU       0.669
PL7BMP       0.561
COSZVU       0.0132

#- Lower 5 (highest to lowest)
D4SBIM      -14.535
V2LCFW      -11.487
0E10MH      -8.472
7U2SWD      -7.216
DBSUQ1      -6.3403
```

Comment: Your "middle 5" sequences have four values in them, which seems a bit confused...

Comment: It's unclear how you identify your "middle" values. The "upper" and "lower" parts are easily acquired by sorting

Comment: The shown code expect *3* cols (0, 1 and 2) and shown data only has *2*...

Comment: More seriously, it is easy to directly load that with pandas (your example code uses it). Just look for `read_csv(..., sep=r'\s\s+', engine='python')` to split on a number of spaces. Then `sort_values` can sort the dataframe on the column of your choice. Try it, show code related to the question and feel free to ask a new question here is stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = []
with open('datafile.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        cols = line.strip().split()
        data.append(cols)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Object','Change'])
df['Change'] = df['Change'].astype(float)




df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='Change', ascending=False)
top_positive = df_sorted[df_sorted['Change'] > 0].head(5)

#values between -2 and 2
middle_values = df_sorted[(df_sorted['Change'] >= -2) & (df_sorted['Change'] <= 2)]



middle_positive = middle_values[middle_values['Change'] > 0].head(4)
middle_negative = middle_values[middle_values['Change'] < 0].tail(4)

bottom_values = df_sorted.tail(5)

print("Upper 5:\n",top_positive.to_string(index=False))
print("\nMiddle -ve (-0.x to -2)):\n", middle_negative.iloc[::-1].to_string(index=False))
print("\nMiddle +ve (0.x to 2):\n", middle_positive.to_string(index=False))
print("\nLower 5:\n", bottom_values.iloc[::-1].to_string(index=False))
```

instead of .to_string(index=False) u can set

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Object','Change']).set_index('Object')
```

it will work

Comment: Can we rename `Column1  Column2` to `Object and Change` and remove the index?

Comment: This answer produces the output though there are still adjustments to be made.. This answer is working on my end..

Comment: `Upper 5:
    Column1  Column2
13  2B2L1X  20.3100
0   UQ8SAI  12.5390
2   KCP5LY  10.3100
3   I2GYD5   7.3210
24  QQTW8M   7.2584

Middle -ve (-0.x to -2)):
    Column1  Column2
8   0IS2PR  -0.6860
14  OEMHED  -0.5610
7   SRS7A0  -0.5000
16  1GPMVW  -0.3401

Middle +ve (0.x to 2):
    Column1  Column2
17  3GYYED   0.8210
5   BL19JU   0.6690
9   PL7BMP   0.5610
22  COSZVU   0.0132

Lower 5:
    Column1  Column2
10  D4SBIM -14.5350
1   V2LCFW -11.4870
6   0E10MH  -8.4720
12  7U2SWD  -7.2160
19  DBSUQ1  -6.3403`

Comment: there are others alternatives also for .to_string(index=False) such as .to_markdown(index=False)

Comment: Can the four frames be joined? Like in the `Upper 5    Middle -ve    Middle +ve     Lower 5` so that it will be more readable in a few lines. By the way, .head(4) and tail(4) will be changed to 5 to balance the table.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a Dataframe for something so trivial.

Just build a list of 2-tuples (the tokens from each line of the file) then sort the list and finally extract relevant content

```
FILENAME = '/Volumes/G-Drive/datafile.txt'

content = []

def mid(content):
    t: list[tuple[int, ...]] = []
    u: list[tuple[int, ...]] = []
    for k, (_, v) in enumerate(content):
        if v <= 0 and v >= -2:
            t.append((v, k))
        elif v >= 0 and v <= 2:
            u.append((v, k))
    return max(t)[1], min(u)[1]


with open(FILENAME) as data:
    for line in data:
        t, v = line.split()
        content.append((t, float(v)))
    print('#- Upper 5 (positive highest to lowest)')
    content.sort(key=lambda e: e[1])
    for e in content[-5:][::-1]:
        print(*e)
    i, j = mid(content)
    print('\n#- Middle 1 (Top 4 starting from -0 to -2 or more)')
    for e in content[i-3:i+1]:
        print(*e)
    print('\n#- Middle 2 (Top 4 starting from +0 to +2 or more)')
    for e in content[j:j+4][::-1]:
        print(*e)
    print('\n#- Lower 5 (highest to lowest)')
    for e in content[:5]:
        print(*e)
```

**Output:**

```
#- Upper 5 (positive highest to lowest)
2B2L1X 20.31
UQ8SAI 12.539
KCP5LY 10.31
I2GYD5 7.321
QQTW8M 7.2584

#- Middle 1 (Top 4 starting from -0 to -2 or more)
0IS2PR -0.686
OEMHED -0.561
SRS7A0 -0.5
1GPMVW -0.3401

#- Middle 2 (Top 4 stating from +0 to +2 or more)
3GYYED 0.821
BL19JU 0.669
PL7BMP 0.561
COSZVU 0.0132

#- Lower 5 (highest to lowest)
D4SBIM -14.535
V2LCFW -11.487
0E10MH -8.472
7U2SWD -7.216
DBSUQ1 -6.3403
```

Comment: Middle 1 from `-0 to -1` and Middle 2 from `+0 to +1`

Comment: @DarCoy -0 to -1 or -0 to -2 as indicated in the original question